# How do we remove date and hours in the URL's?

Tags: java, sql

Currently i am getting all the below URL's from the list using the java.

```
1. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/dt=2017-10-05/hour=00/
2. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/dt=2017-10-05/
3. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/done_dt=2017-10-05.lst
4. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/20171005/00/
5. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/20171005/
6. Input - hdfs://location-one/mnt/hadoop/abc/cded/2017-10-05/
7. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/20171005/
8. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/dt=2017-10-05/hour=00/_done
9. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/
```

How do i remove the dates, hours if it presents and finally pass this values to the database to the exact match.

Required output is:

```
1. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/
2. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/
3. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/
4. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/
5. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/
6. Input - hdfs://location-one/mnt/hadoop/abc/cded/
7. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/
8. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/
9. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/
```

My Code:

```
String rawDataPath= Input.replaceAll("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}/", "");
System.out.println("rawDataPath: " +rawDataPath);
```

If the date is not present it fails.

Comment: @Ghostcat, Added my code and it fails if the date is not present in the URL.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it fails' ?

Comment: Be aware that `/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/2017100%35/` is a perfectly valid URL that represents the same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex pattern replacement is inadequate. Given your samples it should read:

```
String rawDataPath = 
  Input.replaceAll(
    "/((((done_)?dt=)?(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}|\\d{8})(\\.[^/]+)?)|((hour=)?\\d{2}))(?=(/|$))|(?<=/)_done(?=$)"
  , "");
```

This will eliminate dates and hours from all of your samples while preserving their respective remainder.

There are less complicated regex patterns that would do the job and catch some more varieties (e.g. matching date parameters which are differently named). However, this comes at the risk that the pattern would match in cases you do not want it to. Thus ...

**To turn this into production code, make sure that you have an exhaustive specification of the patterns that you want to remove and adjust the regex to precisely match these cases and none else !**

Alternatively, consider a muti-tiered approach or tackle the job differently (e.g. by splitting the path into components, checking them individually, reassembling them; possibly your follow-up code could even work on the split representation).

Comment: @collapsar- Thanks for your response. It is working fine for all combination, except this one -                                                               
7. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/20171005/
         8. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/dt=2017-10-05/hour=00/_done

Comment: @AdalarasanSachithanantham I have complemented the regex to delete a trailing `_done` from the input (case 9); case 8, however, produces the desired result as you specified.

Answer (score 1):

This here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> examples = Arrays.asList(
   "1. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/dt=2017-10-05/hour=00/",
   "9. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/");
 for (String input : examples) {
   System.out.println(input.replaceAll("dt=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}/hour=\\d{2}/", ""));
  }
}
```

Prints

> 1. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/
> 2. Input - /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/

And please note: I simply **enhanced** your regex to match "all" of that timestamp content. And as you can see: that works nicely for lines that dont have a timestamp, too. Because `replaceAll()` only replaces on match. No match, no replace.